# Validation Test scores

Tags: java, validation

I need help in the field of validating data. For some reason I keep getting a incompatible error. I checked a couple times now that I have the right type. What is wrong, 2 classes. The error  is int the driver class keep bringing incompatible types in "name = student.setName( input);". Please explain why? **Updated**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class P5A
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
    System.out.println( "Always Show" );

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    student student = new student();

    String name, validate, valtests;
    int tests, score;


    System.out.print( "Please enter the students Name: ");
    String input = reader.nextLine();
    student.getName( input);
    student.validateData();
        System.out.print( "Please enter Test (As number 1-3 for test number, then test score):  ");
        tests = student.getScore( reader.nextInt(), reader.nextInt());
        student.setTests(tests);

        System.out.print( "Please enter Test (As number 1-3 for test number, then test score):  ");
        tests = student.getScore( reader.nextInt(), reader.nextInt());
        student.setTests(tests);

        System.out.print( "Please enter Test (As number 1-3 for test number, then test score):    ");
        tests = student.getScore( reader.nextInt(), reader.nextInt());
        student.setTests(tests);

         System.out.println( student.toString());



}//end of main mthod
}//end of main class/Driver
```

Here is the second class, **It has been edited Since the question was posted**.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class student
{
private String name, result, testchange;
private int test1, test2, test3;

public student ()
{
    name = "";
    test1 = 0;
    test2 = 0;
    test3 = 0;
    result = "";
}//constructor

 public String getName (String name)
{
    return name;
}//getting the name

public String validateData ()
{
    if (name == null)name = "Error! Must enter at least one character";
    return name;
}//end validation method

public int getScore (int i, int score)
{
    if (i == 1) test1 = score;
    else if( i == 2)test2 = score;
    else test3 = score;

    if ( i == 1 )return test1;
    else if ( i == 2 ) return test2;
    else return test3;
}//getting score of tests

public String validateTests ()
{
    String testschange;
    if (test1 < 0 || test1 > 100) {
         testschange =  " You have entered an invalid number, between 1-100. \nPlease restart!";
         testschange = Integer.toString( test1 ) ;
    }
    else if (test2 < 0 || test2 > 100) {
        testschange =  " You have entered an invalid number, between 1-100. " + 
        "\nPlease restart!";
        testschange = Integer.toString(test2);
    }
    else if (test3 < 0 || test3 > 100) {
        testschange =  " You have entered an invalid number, between 1-100. " + 
        "\nPlease restart!";
        testschange = Integer.toString(test3);
    }
    else String.toInteger(testchange) = test1 || test2 || test3;
    return testchange;
}//validating the test scores and tesing each one against method

public int getAverage ()
{
    int average;
    average = (int) Math.round((test1 + test2 + test3)/ 3.0);
    return average;
}//getting a average of all the scores

public int getHighScore()
{
    int highscore;
    highscore = test1;
    if (test2 > highscore) highscore = test2;
    if  (test3 > highscore)highscore = test3;
    return highscore;
}//getting the highscores of all three

public String toString()
{
    String str;
    str = "Name: " + name + 
           "\nTest1:  " + test1 +
           "\nTest2:  " + test2 +
           "\nTest3:  " + test3 +
           "\nAverage: " + getAverage() + 
           "\nHighscore: " + getHighScore();
    return str;
}//putting all the tests together to view in termainal


}
```

Comment: First rule of string equality:  you don't compare strings with `==`.  Second, your problem statement is extremely broad.  You would be best served by narrowing down what is specifically going wrong and where.

Comment: I'll add to Makoto comment, you have to study again how to program properly. go over your code and try to think if logically correct. for example: public String getName (String nm), is wrong getName should only return "name", and not set it with nm. use a void setter function to fix this.

Comment: Please explain to me why you need to have 2 methods in getting something from driver and setting a variable to something?

Comment: my teacher doesn't explain stuff very well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line in error:

```
name = student.setName( input);
```

Your `setName` method on your `student` object returns `void`; that is, it doesn't return a value back.  You can't assign the result of a void method to anything.

Remove the assignment and that will clear up one of your errors.